Prove that $X$ is $\mathcal{F}/\Sigma$-measurable if and only if $f_\alpha(X)$ is a random variable for every $\alpha \in \Lambda$.
Let $f_\alpha : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function for each $\alpha \in \Lambda$ and let $\Sigma := \sigma(f_\alpha : \alpha \in \Lambda)$. Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ be a measurable space and let $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function. Prove that $X$ is $\mathcal{F}/\Sigma$-measurable (i.e., $X^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal{F}$ for every $A \in \Sigma$) if and only if $f_\alpha(X)$ is a random variable for every $\alpha \in \Lambda$.
Definitions from the materials I'm using:

Let $\{h_\alpha \mid \alpha \in \Lambda\}$ be a set of functions, i.e.,
$$h_\alpha : S \to \mathbb{R} \quad \forall \alpha \in \Lambda.$$
Def. The $\sigma$-algebra generated by the set $\{h_\alpha \mid \alpha \in \Lambda\}$, denoted by $\sigma(h_\alpha \mid \alpha \in \Lambda)$, is defined as the smallest (in the sense of inclusion) $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma^*$ on $S$ such that $h_\alpha$ is $\Sigma^*$-measurable for all $\alpha \in \Lambda$.
Def. A function $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ that is measurable with respect to $\mathcal{F}$ on the probability space $ (\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}) $ is called a random variable.

My proof currently:
$\implies$:
Assume that $X$ is $\mathcal{F}/\Sigma$-measurable. Since each $f_\alpha$ is $\Sigma/\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable (by the definition of $\Sigma = \sigma(f_\alpha : \alpha \in \Lambda)$), the composition $f_\alpha \circ X$ is $\mathcal{F}/\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable. This follows from the fact that the composition of measurable functions is measurable when the $\sigma$-algebras align appropriately.
For any Borel set $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, we have:
$$(f_\alpha(X))^{-1}(B) = X^{-1}(f_\alpha^{-1}(B)) \in \mathcal{F},$$
since $f_\alpha^{-1}(B) \in \Sigma$ and $X$ is $\mathcal{F}/\Sigma$-measurable. Therefore, $f_\alpha(X)$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable for each $\alpha \in \Lambda$.
$\Leftarrow$:
I'm having trouble with the $\Leftarrow$ side of the proof. Also, is the $\Rightarrow$ side of my proof even sensible?

Your proof of $(\implies)$ is correct. For the converse, prove that the family
$$\mathcal{A} = \{ A \subseteq \mathbb{R} : X^{-1}[A] \in \mathcal{F} \}$$
is a $\sigma$-algebra such that all $f_{\alpha}$, $\alpha \in \Lambda$, are $\mathcal{A}/\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable.${}^{\dagger}$ Then by definition $\Sigma \subseteq \mathcal{A}$ and so $X$ is $\mathcal{F}/\Sigma$-measurable.
$(\dagger)$ Equivalently, $\{ f_{\alpha}^{-1}[B] : \alpha \in \Lambda, B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$.

Thank you for the tip! I have provided the proof as the answer to this question. Would you mind going over it quickly? Thank you in advance!

Actually, I started questioning whether the composition $f_\alpha \circ X$ is actually $\mathcal{F}$-measurable in the $\Rightarrow$ proof. By default, the composition of two measurable functions is not necessarily measurable. The composition would be $\mathcal{F}$-measurable if X is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable which it is and $f_\alpha$ is a Borel function. (This according to the following lemma from my materials: Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a Borel function. If $h$ is $\Sigma$-measurable then $f_\alpha \circ h$ is $\Sigma$-measurable.) Is $f_\alpha$ a Borel function?

@gurkin398 Your proof of $(\implies)$ is correct. Directly from the definition if $f$ is $\Sigma/\Theta$-measurable and $g$ is $\Theta/\Xi$-measurable, then $g \circ f$ is $\Sigma/\Xi$-measurable. The source of confusion is that when a function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is called measurable (without naming any $\sigma$-algebras), by default it means it is $\mathcal{M}/\mathcal{B}$-measurable, where $\mathcal{M}$ are the Lebesgue measurable sets and $\mathcal{B}$ are the Borel sets. Since $\mathcal{M}/\mathcal{B}$ is not compatible with itself, such a composition may not be measurable.

Also for a function $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ the $\Sigma$-measurability defaults to $\Sigma/\mathcal{B}$-measurability. Thus the lemma from your materials is a special case of the previous theorem - $\Sigma/\mathcal{B}$ composed with $\mathcal{B}/\mathcal{B}$ gives $\Sigma/\mathcal{B}$. Once you fill in the implicit $\sigma$-algebras for every mention of measurability in the proof, it should all make perfect sense.

The proof for the converse based on the tips that Adayah provided:
$\Leftarrow$:
Assume that for each $\alpha \in \Lambda$, $f_\alpha(X)$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable. Define:
$$
\mathcal{A} = \{ A \subseteq \mathbb{R} : X^{-1}[A] \in \mathcal{F} \}.
$$
Then $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ because:

$\mathbb{R} \in \mathcal{A}$ since $X^{-1}[\mathbb{R}] = \Omega \in
   \mathcal{F}$.
If $A \in \mathcal{A}$, then $X^{-1}[A^c] = \Omega \setminus
   X^{-1}[A] \in \mathcal{F}$, so $A^c \in \mathcal{A}$.
If $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \subseteq \mathcal{A}$, then $X^{-1}\left[
   \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n \right] = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty X^{-1}[A_n]
   \in \mathcal{F}$, so $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n \in \mathcal{A}$.

Our goal is to show that $\Sigma \subseteq \mathcal{A}$. Since each $f_\alpha(X)$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable, for any Borel set $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, we have:
$$
X^{-1}\left( f_\alpha^{-1}[B] \right) = (f_\alpha(X))^{-1}[B] \in \mathcal{F}.
$$
This implies that $f_\alpha^{-1}[B] \in \mathcal{A}$ for all $\alpha \in \Lambda$ and $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.
Since $\Sigma$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all sets of the form $f_\alpha^{-1}[B]$, it follows that $\Sigma \subseteq \mathcal{A}$. Therefore, for any $A \in \Sigma$, we have $X^{-1}[A] \in \mathcal{F}$, which means $X$ is $\mathcal{F}/\Sigma$-measurable.

Well done. A minor remark: using the fact that $\Sigma$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all sets of the form $f_{\alpha}^{-1}[B]$ is fine. But if you want to stick closer to the definition, you may instead show that all $f_{\alpha}$ are $\mathcal{A}$-measurable. That will directly imply that $\Sigma \subseteq \mathcal{A}$.

Out of pure interest I constructed the following: for any Borel set $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$: $f_\alpha^{-1}(B)$.
We need to show that $f_\alpha^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{A}$, i.e., that $X^{-1}(f_\alpha^{-1}(B)) \in \mathcal{F}$.
But observe that: $X^{-1}(f_\alpha^{-1}(B)) = (f_\alpha \circ X)^{-1}(B).$
Since $f_\alpha(X)$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable by assumption, we have $(f_\alpha(X))^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{F}$. Therefore: $X^{-1}(f_\alpha^{-1}(B)) \in \mathcal{F},$  which means $f_\alpha^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{A}$.
Thus, each $f_\alpha$ is $\mathcal{A}$-measurable.

That's it, good job.

Thanks! How does this directly imply that $\Sigma \subseteq \mathcal{A}$ tho?

By the very definition $\Sigma$ is the smallest (with respect to inclusion) $\sigma$-algebra such that all $f_{\alpha}$ are $\Sigma$-measurable. Since you have proved that all $f_{\alpha}$ are $\mathcal{A}$-measurable, $\Sigma$ must be smaller than $\mathcal{A}$ by that definition, i.e. $\Sigma \subseteq \mathcal{A}$.
